# How to convert CONNECT BY in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

Can anyone suggest how to convert CONNECT BY Oracle query into Greenplum. Greenplum doesn't support recursive queries. So, we can not use WITH RECURSIVE. Is there any alternate solution to re-write the below query.

```
 SELECT child_id, Parnet_id, LEVEL , SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (child_id,'/') as HIERARCHY
 FROM pathnode
 START WITH Parnet_id = child_id
 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR child_id = Parnet_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to do this but it will be a one-off per query.  You will need to create a function that loops through your pathnode table and "return next" to return each row.  You can search on this site to find examples of doing this with PostgreSQL 8.2.

Work is happening to rebase Greenplum to PostgreSQL 8.3, 8.4, and so on.  Those later PostgreSQL versions support "with recursive" which is the ANSI SQL way to write your SQL but Greenplum doesn't support it yet.  When it does get supported by Greenplum, I don't think it will perform all that well.  The query will force looping and individual row lookups.  This works great in an OLTP database but not so well for an MPP database.

I suggest you transform your data in Oracle with a VIEW and then just dump the view to a file to load into Greenplum.  The DDL of having a self-referencing, N-level table will never be a good idea in an MPP database.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have created recursive function. It is working fine for N-levels.